# How can I control an image's size

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a skilled database / application programmer for the PC.  I am also an ignorant html / javascript / web programmer.

I am creating some documentation about some .Net assemblies for our intranet. Ideally I would like to display an image full size if the browser window can fit it.  If not then I would like to reduce it and toggle between a small version and full size version by a click.  It is a dependency chart and can be different sizes for different pages.  I would prefer a single function to handle this but being it is for our use none of the requirements I mentioned is set in stone.  I would like to make it work well but nothing is mandatory.

I read a lot of stuff but couldn't find anything that matched what I wanted.  First I tried this (after a few iterations):

```
<img src='Dependancy Charts/RotairAORFQ.png' width='100%' onclick='this.src="Dependancy Charts/RotairAORFQ.png";this.width=this.naturalWidth;this.height=this.naturalHeight;' ondblclick='this.src="Dependancy Charts/RotairAORFQ.png";this.width="100%";'>
```

It has problems.  First off it enlarges a small image and it looks funny.  Second I would have to put the code in every page.  Third it requires a double click to restore it.  I was going to live with those short commings but the double click fails.  I can't figure out how to restore it.

So I tried to get fancy.  I couldn't figure out how to get past problem 1, but solved 2 and 3 by creating a function in a separate file.  Then I ran into what appeared to be the same problem.  This was my second attempt:

```
function ImageToggle(Image)
{

    if (ImageToggle.FullSize == 'undefined')
        ImageToggle.FullSize = false;

    if (ImageToggle.FullSize)
        {
            Image.width='100%';
            ImageToggle.FullSize = false;
        }
    else
        {
            Image.width=Image.naturalWidth;
            ImageToggle.FullSize = true;
        }

    return 0
}
```

And in my page:

```
<img src='Dependancy Charts/RotairAORFQ.png' width='100%' onclick='ImageToggle(this)'>
```

Can what I want be done?  It doesn't sound impossible.  If it is a large amount of effort would be required then alternate suggestions are acceptable.

Comment: didn't you try to control img size in css?

Comment: couldn't you use the large image in all cases and scale it using css media query on screen max-width? if you do need to click to change the size then you should be able to add or subtract a class on click that pushes the image to whatever size the class has set in your css.

Comment: Nope.  How do you do that on a click event?  And how do you get the current browser window size in CSS?

Comment: I dont know Doc, could I?

Comment: I just did a search on "css add or subtract a class" and did not find any results.  The only adding of classes I have ever done was with a collection or list.  I have never subtracted a class.  Can you provide a link that may explain what you are talking about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your help.  Rob and Mike both pointed me to an excellent solution.  I now have my page load with an image that fits the browser window, resizes with the browser and if the user is interested they can expand the image and scrollbars appear if necessary.  I got this to work in a function so minimal code is needed for each page.

To load the image:

```
<p style="overflow:auto;">
    <img src='Dependancy Charts/RotairAORFQ.png' width="100%" onclick='ImageToggle(this)'>
</p>
```

And the function:

```
function ImageToggle(Image)
{
    if (ImageToggle.FullSize == 'undefined')
        ImageToggle.FullSize = false;

    if (ImageToggle.FullSize)
        {
            Image.style="max-width: 100%";
            ImageToggle.FullSize = false;
        }
    else
        {
            Image.style="max-width: none";
            Image.width=Image.naturalWidth;
            ImageToggle.FullSize = true;
        }

    return 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably interested in the `max-width: 100%` CSS property, rather than a flat-out `width:100%`. If you have a tiny image, it'll stay tiny. If you have a huge image, it gets resized to the width of the containing element.

For example: http://jsbin.com/kabepo/1/edit uses a small and a huge image, both with max-width:100%. As you can see, the small image is untouched, the huge image is resized to something sensible.

Comment: I used max-width but it had the same effect as width.  It also failed in my function the same as width did.  Perhaps I did not incorporate it correctly?  This is what I tried: if (ImageToggle.FullSize)
  {
   Image.style="max-width: 100%;"
   ImageToggle.FullSize = false;
  }
 else
  {
   Image.width=Image.naturalWidth;
   ImageToggle.FullSize = true;
  }

Comment: that would be `image.style.maxWidth = "100%";` (image.style is not the same as the style attribute)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend that you set a the `max-width: 100%` CSS property for the image.

This will prevent the image's width from expanding to be greater than the container's width.

You can also do the same with `max-height: 100%` if you are having problems with the image overflowing vertically.

Please see this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/10hpbuz8/1/) for an example.

(Note: If you set both a width and a height attribute on the `<img>` tag directly or in your CSS file your image will not be scaled proportionally.)

Comment: That example has hard coded values.  I do not wish to hard code anything.

Comment: I looked at this again and those hard coded values appear to be for the div and not the image.  I am not sure what you are proposing.  I already can prevent the image from expanding past the container width.  Are you saying that max-width is better?  And if so can it be toggled?  That is where the big problem is.

Comment: @JohnMaher The hard coded values were indeed just for the div in the example. With javascript you can add the `max-width` property with `element.style.maxWidth = "100%";` and remove it using `element.style.maxWidth = "auto";`.

Answer (score 0):

Does it have to be a toggle or would a mouseover work for you as well?

`<style>`

`.FullSize { width:100px; height:auto; }`

`.FullSize:hover { width:90%; height:auto; }`

`</style>`

`<img src="Dependancy Charts/RotairAORFQ.png" class="FullSize">`

---

Note: when image is made larger IN the page - the surrounding content will be displaced around it - depending on how you have set up the layout.

Also if you have any body margins or table or div paddings, using image width at 100% will make the page scroll. To check just change 90% to 100% and work your way up / down.

You could also force the image to be a specific size until the browser gets made smaller by the user / has a smaller resolution.

---

`<style>`

`.FullSize {width:1000px;max-width:100%;height:auto;}`

`</style>`

`<img src="Dependancy Charts/RotairAORFQ.png" class="FullSize">`

---

A tip:  the image used must be the largest one. So minimum width of lets say 1200 pixels wide (if that is the forced image size you use). That way regardless of size it is it will remain clearer than a small image becoming a large. Since it's an intranet, file size shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I can do a mouseover, that would be fine with me.  I do not want to hard code any sizes.  I have about 40 of these pages to do and each one has a chart of a different size.  I tried this based on your example: <style>

.FullSize { width:100%; }

.FullSize:hover { width:auto; height:auto; }

</style>

<img src="Dependancy Charts/RotairAORFQ.png" class="FullSize"> and it is the closest to what I've been trying to acheive.  The only problem here is some images would now need scroll bars.  How would you recommend resolving this?

Answer (score -1):

if you want to get current browser window size and if you want to do it on a click event so try this in jquery or javascript:

```
<script>

$("#myButton").click(function(){
        var x = window.innerHeight;              // put current window size in x (ie. 400)
});

</script>
```

Comment: `window.innerWidth` also returns the width of the window.